# Does $\operatorname{int} A \subseteq \operatorname{int} B$ imply $\partial A \subseteq \partial B$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A,B \subseteq X$. Clearly, $\operatorname{int} A \subseteq \operatorname{int} B$ does not imply $A \subseteq B$. A counter-example is $A = (1, 2]$ and $B = [1, 2)$.

Does $\operatorname{int} A \subseteq \operatorname{int} B$ imply $\partial A \subseteq \partial B$?

Comment: think before posting? trivial examples suffice.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sometimes what seems trivial to an expert can be challenging for a beginner

Comment: @NickAlger Everyone ought to think first IMO.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma True. But I think this question derives from a genuine conceptual issue here regarding set containment, versus "containment" in the colloquial sense. If you ask a person on the street: does the zero-centered circle of radius 2 contain the zero-centered circle of radius one, they will say yes. And the standard counterexamples are like this.

Comment: The interior of me is a subset of the interior of the room I am in, but my boundary has no point in common with the boundary of the room...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider the example $A=[1,2]$, $B=(0,3)$, then we have that $\text{int}(A)=(1,2)$, $\text{int}(B)=(0,3)$, and $\partial A=\{1,2\}$, and $\partial B=\{0,3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(0,1)$, and let $B=(0,2)$. Then, $\partial A=\{0,1\}\not\subseteq\{0,2\}=\partial B$.