# Let $A, B \subseteq ℂ$, if $A \subseteq B$, then $\partial A \subseteq \partial B$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

Let $A, B \subseteq ℂ$, if $A \subseteq B$, then $\partial A \subseteq \partial B$?

I thought of a counter example but I'm not sure if the boundaries ($\partial$) are context dependent.

Here it is:
$A = ℝ, B = ℂ$

So obviously, $A \subseteq B$, but here's the problem I'm having.
I know that ℝ is both open and closed set (?), and it's boundaries should be an empty set - but does the context of the topology, that since we look at ℝ as $ℝ \subseteq ℂ$, it's boundaries is just ℝ? Thus satisfies a counter example for the said claim?

Comment: A simple counter example would but the disc as a subset of a larger disc.  The boundarys will be non intersecting circles.  The *real* issue is whether $\partial A \subset \overline B$.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is not open as a subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I think the problem is asking for $A$ and $B$ to be equipped with the relative topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb{C}$. In this case, $\mathbb{R}$ is not open and $\mathbb{R}$ equals its boundary.

Comment: It should be intuitively easy to come up with many counter examples.  Just pick an $A$ that is "complete" interior to $B$ so that it's boundary is entirely withing the interior of $B$ and thus misses $A$ and it's boundary entirely.

Comment: Related: [Does $\operatorname{int}A\subseteq\operatorname{int}B$
imply $\partial A\subseteq\partial B$
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344001/560462)

Comment: There's very little reason to think this would be true. A real world example with "common sense" interpretations would be the border of paris must be part of the border of France or the border of a landlocked country must be part of the border of the continent which would be all shoreline.  In fact it be more of a challenge to find a case where it *is* true (although it's not impossible)

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}$ is only clopen in its own topology, not necessarily any other. In general, for a topology defined on a set $S$, $S$ as a set is a clopen subset, but that need not extrapolate to any supersets of $S$ in their own respective topologies.

It's not hard to see that $\mathbb{R}$ is not open in the grander context of $\mathbb{C}$. Take any ball with center in $\mathbb{R}$ and positive radius, and there will be a non-real complex number contained inside (say, just above the center).

---

Anyhow, as a simpler counterexample, just try two circles with differing radii contained in each other, like below:

[image]

Comment: Why do the circles have to meet at a point? Why not have the smaller circle entirely within the interior of the larger.

Comment: Fair; that's simply what came to mind in my head and I didn't think much beyond it working.

Comment: "that's simply what came to mind in my head " well, that's certainly fair. Counter examples are abundent.

Answer (score 1):

$A, B\subset \Bbb{C}$ and $A\subset B$

Then $\overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$.

If $\partial{A}\subset\partial{B}$ then $\overline{A}\setminus \overset{o}A\subset\overline{B}\setminus \overset{o}B$

implies $\overset{o}B\subset \overset{o}A$

$A\subset B$ doesn't imply $\overset{o}B\subset \overset{o}A$.

Counter examples : Choose $A\subset B $ such that $\overset{o}B\not\subset \overset{o}A$.

$A=C_0(1) :\{z:|z|=1\}$ , $A=C_0(2) :\{z:|z|=2\}$

Then $A\subset B$ but $\overset{o}B=D(0, 2) $ and $\overset{o}A=D(0, 1) $.

---

Now you can see why your example won't work.

$A=\Bbb{R}\subset \Bbb{C}$ is nowhere dense. It's interior is empty! Empty set is subset of every set. So any set containing $\Bbb{R}$ won't provide a counter example.